# gradle custom task execution phase

Tags: gradle

This question is for gradle (>= 2.4). I would like to write a custom task like the following:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

```
class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println 'hello from GreetingTask'
    }
}

task hello(type: GreetingTask)
```

how can I make this task run during execution phase? Is passing an empty closure with

```
<< {

}
```

the only solution?

## Edit

the task is supposed to be used in a multiproject build with several tasks as dependencies.

I'd like that the command `gradle build` would build all the projects by saying something like

```
`build.dependsOn(hello)`
```

but seems that the task hello is called during configuration phase of the build.

Comment: That is what it looks like to me, but I don't know much about this.

Comment: Without the closure, what happens when you execute `gradle hello` ?

Comment: @jaco0646 you are calling the task directly. I need it to be called during execution phase and not configuration phase

Comment: Calling the task directly is the execution phase: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html.

Comment: @jaco0646 what if this task is a dependency of another one?

Comment: `task anotherOne(dependsOn : hello)`  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies

Comment: @jaco0646 I mean will it be called during execution phase if it is a dependency of another task? The question is "how to make the task be called during execution in general"

Comment: you can just call it from the commandline: "gradle hello". otherwise you should declare a dependency on this task from one of your other tasks you have in your build. To help you best, can you elaborate a bit about your usecase here?

Comment: @ReneGroeschke please see the edit. I am quite new to gradle so I am not sure what is important to specify and what not.

Comment: @iggy why do you think the task is executed during configuration phase?

Comment: @ReneGroeschke I guess I am not exactly sure how execution phase works when we don't say `doLast` or `<< {}` for a task

Comment: @ReneGroeschke I would really appreciate if you could elaborate how this works or maybe point me to a link that would explain this mechanism

Comment: @iggy your question contains a link explaining that mechanism. It says: *Gradle will call the method when the task executes*. Note the wording. It says "when the task executes". Not "when the task is configured". So the method annotated with `@TaskAction` is what the task does, during the execution phase. It also says: *You don't have to use a method to define the behaviour for the task. You could, for instance, call doFirst() or doLast() with a closure in the task constructor to add behaviour*. So this TaskAction-based mechanism is just another way of telling the task what to do when executed

Comment: @JBNizet explained it very well. To understand the phases of a gradle build I recommend you the according gradle user guide section at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to a *build.gradle* file:

```
class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println 'hello from GreetingTask'
    }
}

task hello(type: GreetingTask) {
    println "This is the configuration phase"

    doFirst {
        println "This is the execution phase"
    }
}
```

Now execute `gradle hello`. The output you will see is

```
This is the configuration phase
:hello
This is the execution phase
hello from GreetingTask

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see, the output from the task occurs after the `doFirst()`, which definitely happens during the execution phase.

Comment: thanks for explaining, I had some gaps in understanding how configuration phase in gradle works